# pthread_cond_timedwait with monolic timer sometimes timeouts later than expected

Tags: c++, pthreads

I use pthread_cond_timedwait with monolitic timer. I would like to ask if there is some problem in my example or what is the reason, when sometimes pthread_cond_timedwait waits longer than timeout specified(300ms in example).

Example follows:

```
#include <pthread.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>

pthread_cond_t cond;
pthread_condattr_t cond_attr;
pthread_mutex_t mutex;

void *thread1(void *attr)
{
    struct timespec ts;
    clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, &ts);
    //fprintf(stderr, "starting timer for %ds, %dms\n", (period/1000), (period % 1000));

    auto period = 300;
    auto sec = (period / 1000);
    auto nsec = (period % 1000) * 1000000;
    fprintf(stderr, "[start] ts.sec=%d ts.ns = %d\n", ts.tv_sec, ts.tv_nsec);
    if ((ts.tv_nsec + nsec) > 999999999)
    {
        ts.tv_sec += sec + 1;
        ts.tv_nsec = nsec - (1000000000 - ts.tv_nsec);
        fprintf(stderr, "[expected end] ts.sec=%d ts.ns = %d\n", ts.tv_sec, ts.tv_nsec);
        //fprintf(stderr, "timeout = %dms\n", (sec * 1000) + ((1000000000 - ts_now.tv_nsec + ts.tv_nsec)/1000000));
    }
    else
    {
        ts.tv_sec += sec;
        ts.tv_nsec += nsec;
        fprintf(stderr, "[expected end] ts.sec=%d ts.ns = %d\n", ts.tv_sec, ts.tv_nsec);
        //fprintf(stderr, "timeout = %dms\n", (sec * 1000) + ((ts.tv_nsec - ts_now.tv_nsec) / 1000000));
    }
    while (true)
    {
        auto ret = pthread_cond_timedwait(&cond, &mutex, &ts);
        if (ret == ETIMEDOUT)
        {
            struct timespec ts2;
            clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, &ts2);

            fprintf(stderr, "[end] ts.sec=%d ts.ns = %d\n", ts2.tv_sec, ts2.tv_nsec);
            auto seconds = ts2.tv_sec - ts.tv_sec;
            auto nseconds = ts2.tv_nsec - ts.tv_nsec;
            if (nseconds < 0)
            {
                seconds--;
                nseconds = 1000000000 - nseconds;
            }
            fprintf(stderr, "[end] diff = %dms\n", (seconds * 1000) + (nseconds / 1000000));
            break;
        }
        if (ret != 0)
        {
            fprintf(stderr, "ret: %m\n");
        }
    }
    return nullptr;
}

    int main()
{
    pthread_t tid1;

    pthread_mutex_init(&mutex, nullptr);
    pthread_condattr_init(&cond_attr);
    pthread_condattr_setclock(&cond_attr, CLOCK_MONOTONIC);
    pthread_cond_init(&cond, &cond_attr);

    pthread_create(&tid1, nullptr, thread1, nullptr);

    pthread_join(tid1, nullptr);

    return 0;
}
```

to compile:

```
g++ -std=c++11 main.cpp -lpthread
```

output:

```
dev@ pthread $./a.out
[start] ts.sec=58842 ts.ns = 602310036
[expected end]: ts.sec=58842 ts.ns = 902310036
[end] ts.sec=58842 ts.ns = 903171492
[end] diff = 0ms
dev@ pthread $./a.out
[start] ts.sec=58844 ts.ns = 378002207
[expected end]: ts.sec=58844 ts.ns = 678002207
[end] ts.sec=58844 ts.ns = 799322723
[end] diff = 121ms
```

Comment: <O/T> since you're using C++11, you should use [`std::thread`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread) and related rather than pthreads.

Comment: Your computer will be doing other stuff as well as executing your program.  You might just be unlucky that it had its mind on something else at the exact moment your timer was set to expire.

Comment: do you mean that the thread waits 300ms longer than it's supposed to? Or that it's waiting slightly longer than 300ms? Waiting slightly longer is allowed, the general rule for sleeps is they're guaranteed to wait at least as long as specified, perhaps more, never less. From the [man page](https://linux.die.net/man/3/pthread_cond_timedwait) "an error is returned if the absolute time specified by `abstime` passes (that is, system time equals or exceeds `abstime`) ... ". If it's consistently waiting 300ms longer than you expect, double check the sleep time.

Comment: Yes, sometimes waits 300 ms longer than it's supposed to. Yes, waiting slightly longer is not a problem, but for example when it's waiting 280ms longer, I think it's quite a big difference. It's not consistently waiting 300ms longer than I expect, most of the time it's correct, like 8 times from 10 runs.

Answer (score 3):

You are invoking undefined behavior by calling `pthread_cond_timedwait()` without locking the associated mutex.

The [POSIX documentation for `pthread_cond_timedwait()`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/pthread_cond_timedwait.html) states:

> **DESCRIPTION**
>
> The `pthread_cond_timedwait()` and `pthread_cond_wait()` functions
>   shall block on a condition variable. The application shall ensure that
>   these functions are called with `mutex` locked by the calling thread;
>   otherwise, an error (for `PTHREAD_MUTEX_ERRORCHECK` and robust
>   mutexes) or undefined behavior (for other mutexes) results.

Any timing issues could easily be the result of "strangeness" from this undefined behavior.

And as noted in the comments, there is not any guarantee how quickly the error return occurs.

Comment: Indeed, thank you. I fixed it now but the behaviour is still the same.